# How to read a plist and create different arrays from its content in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, plist

I've got a `.plist` like this:

[image: screenshot of plist]
<sup>Click image for full resolution</sup>

How can I create different arrays for each subpart of items. like `NSArray foodName` with contents of item 0's item 1's to item n's `foodName`

There are lots of items.

Comment: Your plist content is not clear. It's not any plist syntax I've seen. What is supposed to be inside item 1, a multi-line text field? Another array? It's also not clear what you're asking. What content are you trying to break into individual arrays? Your "arrays like NSArray *recipeDetail" bit is not at all clear.

Comment: Try pasting the xml of the plist file. That should make it clearer.

Comment: Oh totally my bad you guys are right

Comment: You need 50 minutes to make noodles with pesto? must be best makarna ever!

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                    NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
self.pFile = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]
                    stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"recipes.plist"];

self.plist = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pFile];
if (!plist) {
    self.plist = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [plist writeToFile:pFile atomically:YES];
}
```

An NSDictionary is probably what you want. Then do a 'for' on it for each recipe / recipeDetail / wherever you're at in the structure?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create "different arrays".

A plist is a textual (or binary) representation of a collection of objects. The valid object kinds come from a small set which includes `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSNumber` & `NSString`. The collection is rooted either in a dictionary or an array, each element of which can be any of the valid object kinds, including further dictionaries and arrays.

When you read the plist in your application the collection of objects is re-created. So if there are nested arrays or dictionaries they are recreated. To access them you just need to use the appropriate sequence of indices (arrays) and/or keys (dictionaries) which specify the element you need. You can store the returned object reference into a variable.

So for example if your plist is a dictionary keyed by vegetable names, each element of which is an array, and the third element of that array is another array of observed weights of that vegetable then you can access that array as follows (code just typed into answer, expect errors):

```
NSDictionary *vegetableInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsofURL:urlOfVegtableInfoPlist"];
NSArray *carrrotObservedWeights = vegetableInfo[@"Carrot"][3];
```

You now have a reference to the required array stored in `carrrotObservedWeights`.

If you are concerned over memory management, first use ARC. Second if you just want the extracted arrays and not the whole plist to be kept you just need to drop the reference to the plist after you've stored strong references to the contained arrays and ARC will clean up for you.

HTH

**Addendum - After question clarified**

First your plist is a dictionary of dictionaries where the containing dictionary has the keys `Item 1`, `Item 2`, etc. These keys carry no information and you would be better off making your plist an *array* of dictionaries.

Next we assume you have read in your plist using one of the standard methods and have a reference to it in `sample` - which is either an `NSDictionary *` if your plist is as shown, or an `NSArray *` if you modify the plist as suggested.

How many ways to do this? Many, here are three.

*Method 1 - Simple Iteration*

The straightforward way to obtain your arrays is simple iteration - iterate over each item and build your arrays. Here is a code fragment for two of the fields assuming the original dictionary of dictionaries:

```
NSMutableArray *foodNames = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableArray *hardnesses = [NSMutableArray new];

for (NSString *itemKey in sample)             // for-in on a dictionary returns the keys
{
   NSDictionary *item = sample[itemKey];      // use the key to obtain the contained dictionary
   [foodNames addObject:item[@"foodName"]];   // extract each item
   [hardnesses addObject:item[@"hardness"]];
}
```

The above fragment if `sample` is an array is similar.

*Method 2 - Keypaths*

If you do switch your plist to an array you can use a *keypath* to obtain all the values in one go. The method `valueforkeypath:` creates an array from an array by extracting the *keypath* - a list of keys separated by dots which allows for dictionaries within dictionaries. In your case the keypath has just one item:

```
NSMutableArray *foodNames = [sample valueForKeyPath:@"foodName"];
NSMutableArray *hardnesses = [sample valueForKeyPath:@"hardness"];
```

This will not work for your plist as shown with a top-level dictionary as they *keypath* is different each time - `Item 1.foodName`, `Item 2.foodName`, etc. - and wildcards (e.g. `*.foodName`) are not supported. A good reason to change your plist to have a top-level array!

*Method 3 - Encapsulated Iteration*

This is just a variation of method 1, but shows how to use the supplied block enumeration methods on `NSDictionary`. Rather than write a `for` loop yourself you can pass the body of the loop as a block to `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:` and it will perform the iteration:

```
NSMutableArray *foodNames = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableArray *hardnesses = [NSMutableArray new];

[sample enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id item, BOOL *stop)
 {
   [foodNames addObject:item[@"foodName"]];
   [hardnesses addObject:item[@"hardness"]];
 }];
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd make the root of the plist an array, but still have each item as a dictionary, so i could do something like this:

```
//ASSUMING YOUR PLIST IS IN RESOURCES FOLDER
NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YOUR_PLIST_FILE_NAME" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *foodArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filepath];

NSMutableArray *foodNames = [[NSMutable Array] init];
NSInteger i = 0;

for (Item *item in foodArray) {
    NSDictionary *itemDict = [foodArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *foodName = [itemDict objectForKey:@"foodName"];
    [foodNames addObject:foodName];

    i++;
}
```

Hope this helps you figure something out!